# Mocking a external function/struct in Rust

Tags: unit-testing, rust, mocking

The problem consists in a solid way to mock external function/structs from crates.

Take a look at this simple code:

```
// Libs
use reqwest::blocking::{get, ClientBuilder};

// Functions
fn get_body_foo() -> String {
    let client = ClientBuilder::new().build().unwrap();
    let res = client.get("https://www.google.com").send().unwrap();
    res.text().unwrap()
}

fn get_body_bar() -> String {
    let res = get("https://www.google.com").unwrap();
    res.text().unwrap()
}
```

In this example, the 2 functions uses the reqwest library in their bodies, without params ( can't use Dependency Injection ).

How exactly could I mock the reqwest library to test all the possibilities?

I mean, in Python the mock is top-level (once the code is reached, the original function is replaced by the mock without modifying the production code). So how to do something similiar in Rust?

I have tried libraries such as `mockall` and `faux`, but any of them let manipulate external crates.

Libraries that creates a dummy server as `mockito` are out of question.

Comment: Testing either of those functions would just be testing `reqwest`, but that's for `reqwest`s tests to do, your crate is *not* the right place to add tests for `reqwest`.

Comment: I think what you actually would like to do instead is to mock `get_body_foo` and `get_body_bar`.

Comment: @cafce25 But mocking the reqwest library'll give the possibility to test how the function treats the response, not test the real "request action". Without it, how the tests would know my function can handle things gracefully?

Comment: @frankenapps The mock'll work for others functions that depends on `get_body_foo` and `get_body_bar`, but not actually testing thoose functions.